# Is it possible to place playlists generated with Spotipy into a folder?

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

I'm trying to use the [spotipy](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.19.0/) library to generate playlists based on my recent listening history. I've been able to successfully create playlists using `user_playlist_create` and then added tracks to it using `user_playlist_add_tracks`.

However I like my playlists organized into folders and would like to do this automatically rather than having to manually move things.

Anyone able to do this?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't appear that folders can be modified through the Web API at this time. From the [Spotify Developer documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/working-with-playlists/#folders):

> #### Folders
>
> Folders are not returned through the Web API, nor can be created using it.